# Why does the buffer not output anything when called more than once?

Tags: php, buffer, ob-start

I have a PHP file called test.php that contains the following code.

```
<?php
$text = 'Grrrrr';
ob_start();
require_once('testinc.php');
$html2 = ob_get_clean();
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($html2);
echo '</pre>';


$text = 'wtf';
ob_start();
require_once('testinc.php');
$html2 = ob_get_clean();
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($html2);
echo '</pre>';


testing('blah');
testing('123');

function testing($text) {
    ob_start();
    require_once('testinc.php');
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($html);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

The testinc.php file contains the following code.

```
<?php
echo $text;
?>
testing
```

When I run the code, the output looks like this.

```
string(13) "Grrrrrtesting"
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
```

**Why is the buffer not working other than the first time and how can I get the output to look like this?**

```
string(13) "Grrrrrtesting"
string(10) "wtftesting"
string(11) "blahtesting"
string(10) "123testing"
```

Comment: have you read documentation for ob_get_clean and require_ONCE?

Comment: Really?! Changing require_once() to include() solves everything.

Comment: using a lot of output buffering usually means your structuring your code wrong

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not use require_once(). Changing the code to include() and it all works out fine.